# why do i keep getting an error from this code

Tags: python, trigonometry

so i keep getting this error
print(float(side / (math.sin(math.radians(float(degree))))))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'

```
import math
# for anyone looking at this input opp, 10.7, 65, sin, no
print("This only works for right triangles")
print("opp = opposite   adj = adjacent")

# variables
side1 = input("Input if your trying to find opposite or adjacent: ")
side = input("input length of one side: ")
degree = input("Input angle cant use the right angle: ")
trig_ratio = input("Input either sin cos tan: ")
pos_angle = input("is the right angle below the angle: ")

# sin
if trig_ratio == "sin"\
        and pos_angle == "no"\
        and side1 == "opp":
    print(float(side / (math.sin(math.radians(float(degree))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're trying to divide a string by a float. The variable `side` is never converted to a float, which is what the "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'" is talking about.

Use `side = float(input("input length of one side: "))` or `print(float(side) / (math.sin(math.radians(float(degree)))))` instead

Comment: Hi Sam, I would do the conversion into float in a different line, this way you could also wrap a `try-except` block around it, but besides that, it you're right. Btw. if you are looking for a job, maybe you should add your location.

Answer (score 0):

your inputted `side` variable is `str`, convert it to `float` before doing any arithmetic operation.

```py
side = float(input("input length of one side: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

input function always returns a string,
Try casting side to a int or float on input

`side = float(input("input length of one side: "))`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to division with string value, i.e., you need to convert "side" value to float first then try for division.

Use below code:

print(float(side) / (math.sin(math.radians(float(degree)))))